# Using a average to get probability of a single occurance in a range of numbers

Tags: java, math, statistics

So this is a interesting statistic related question.

What I have

1. Average
2. Range of possible occurrences

What I'm after

1. The probability of a single occurrence in my range happening

A example would be a average of 10.3 . range of 1-20. Whats the chance 4 occurs? I need to use 10.3 as a sort of weight because if not each occurrence has a 1/20 chance of happening

Is there a statistical formula for something like this?

Coding

```
public void ReboundFormula(double TeamRebound, double OTeamRebound, double OffensiveRebound, double DefensiveRebound,
        double ShotsTotalAverage, double OShotsTotalAverage, double TeamShotAveragePercent, double OTeamShotAveragePercent,
        double PlayerORebound, double PlayerDRebound, double PlayerOPercentRebound, double PlayerDPercentRebound)
{
    //Possible rebounds using amount of shots that "miss" which result in a rebound chance. Note fouls, ball going out of bounds
    //, or other event that causes a rebound to not occur on a missed shot

    predictedPossibleRebounds = (ShotsTotalAverage*(1 -(double) TeamShotAveragePercent/100)) + OShotsTotalAverage*(1 - (double) TeamShotAveragePercent/100);


    Temp = (double) TeamRebound/(TeamRebound+OTeamRebound);

    Temp2 = (double) OTeamRebound/(TeamRebound+OTeamRebound);

    System.out.println("Percent of Team 1 Rebounds: " + Temp + " | Percent of Team 2 Rebound: " + Temp2);

    System.out.println();

    //Predicted rebounds a team will grab of the amount of rebounds they will likely get
    predictedTeamRebound = (double) predictedPossibleRebounds*Temp;

    predictedOTeamRebound = (double) predictedPossibleRebounds*Temp2;

    System.out.println("Amount of Rebounds to Team: " + predictedTeamRebound + " | Amount of Rebounds to OTeam: " + predictedOTeamRebound);
    System.out.println();

    //Rebounds predicted to be grabbed by teams
    Oratio = ((double) OffensiveRebound/TeamRebound)*predictedTeamRebound;
    Dratio = ((double) DefensiveRebound/TeamRebound)*predictedTeamRebound;

    System.out.println("Amount of Offensive Rebounds: " + Oratio + " | Amount of Defensive Rebounds: " + Dratio);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Predicted Rebounds: " + predictedPossibleRebounds + " | Player Offensive Percent: " + PlayerOPercentRebound + " | Player Defensive Percent: " + PlayerDPercentRebound);

    //Player data time
    Temp = (Oratio*(PlayerOPercentRebound/100)) + (Dratio*(PlayerDPercentRebound/100));

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Player Predicted Rebound Total: " + Temp + " | Player Rebound Total Average: " + (PlayerORebound+PlayerDRebound) );
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println( "  " + (int) Math.round((Temp) - (Temp*0.75)) + "     " + (int) Math.round((Temp) - (Temp*0.5)) + "     " + (int) Math.round((Temp) - (Temp*0.25)) + "     " + (int) Math.round((Temp) - (Temp*0.1)) + "    " + (Temp) 
            + "  " + (int) Math.round((Temp) + (Temp*0.1)) + "    " + (int) Math.round((Temp) + (Temp*0.25)) + "     " +  (int) Math.round((Temp) + (Temp*0.5)) + "     " + (int) Math.round((Temp) + (Temp*0.75)));
    System.out.println("-75%  -50%  -25%  -10%   Predicted Average  +10%  +25%   +50%   +75%");
    System.out.println();
```

Feeding data

```
run.ReboundFormula(54, 48.2, 13.662, 40.338, 89.86, 87.06, 45.2, 45.7, 3.7, 6.2, 12.9, 22.8);
```

Comment: The average isn't enough to get a statistical distribution. 10 values at 1 and 10 values at 20 gives the same average as 10 values at 10 and 10 values at 11.

Comment: I can add coding it's just quite large

Comment: Might help to mention the purpose of this program is to use a adjusted average to determine how many "rebounds" a player would grab going thru each possible occurrence

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify the distribution of outcomes. Merely to specify the average and range does not suffice. For example, an unbalanced die with a 1/12 chance of reading 1 and a 3/12 chance of reading 5, other outcomes having equal probability, averages 3.83. However, other unbalanced dice are also possible with the same average, for example a die with a 1/12 chance of reading 2 and a 3/12 chance of reading 6.

I suspect that what you want is a [*binomial* distribution.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialDistribution.html) The binomial distribution results from a finite number of discrete trials (as your program's *rebounds*), each of which either succeeds or fails, each trial of equal weight.

If you follow the link, you will see many formulas, probably more than you wanted, but a principle underlies the formulas and the principle is what you mainly want to grasp. That won't be so easy, but once you have grasped the principle the chief formulas will naturally follow.

Comment: Problem is with my adjusted average I do not have a distribution of outcomes. I was thinking of finding the standard deviation of the actual data and applying it to my new average

Comment: If you have the data, you can test to figure out the distribution, or if you just want to know the probability of any given value range, you could count the number of datapoints in that range and divide by the total number of results. The first is more elegant, the second easy to implement.